# How do I grab certain text on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This grabs td tags and etc

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>

var td = document.getElementsByTagName(“td”);
for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    document.write(‘td #’ + i + ‘<br />’);
}

</script>
```

How do I make the equivalent of it to grab certain text

For example, if I have

```
hello world
by world
hello goodbye
yellow submarine
yo hello
```

How do I grab the "hello"'s in all that text

Comment: What is your goal? If you tell us what you're trying to do, we'll be better able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery's [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) should help you out.

http://jsfiddle.net/akxWF/1/

JS

```
$('body').find('*:contains("hello")').each(function(){
    var h = $(this).html(); 
    //alert(h); 
    h = h.replace('hello', '<span class="highlight">hello</span>');
    $(this).html(h); 
}); ​
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>hello some more text</td><td>test</td>   
    </tr>
</table>
<div>hello testing<div>More data</div></div>
<span>hello</span>
```

CSS

```
.highlight{
 background-color:yellow;    
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all the "hello" in span tag and give it a class 'hello"

```
<span class="hello">hello</span> world
by world
<span class="hello">hello</span> goodbye
yellow submarine
yo hello
```

Using  jquery

```
var allHello = $('.hello').text();
```

Other way you could do is by using regex but its not needed if you know your content.

Answer (score 0):

The common method followed for screen scraping is to put your text that needs to be captured or searched inside a DIV tag with a ID. Once this is done, you will be able to do getElementsByTagName of the DIV tag's ID to get the entire text.

Hope this is clear. If this is not what you are looking for, I would suggest you append more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I grab the "hello"'s in all that text

I'm not sure I get the question, but to grab the "hello" 's you could do:

```
var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0],
    td = (td.textContent || td.innerText || ""),
    hello = td.match(/hello/gi);
```

this will return a regular javascript array with all the "hello" 's ?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8QNtn/)
​